# Regresar state dependiendo de una condición

Tags: react-native, redux

Queria regresar un valor al state dependiendo de la condicion:

```
const reducerPrueba5 = (state=null, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'AGREGAR_A_CARRITO':
  if(action.vaciar){
   return state=null
  }else {
   return state=action.carrito
  }  
  default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Pero me sale un mensaje de error diciendo que retorna undefined.
¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Comment: no puedes devolver una asignación. Devuelve `null` y `action.carrito` respectivamente en el if y else. O si quieres asignar, quita el `return`.

Answer (score -1):

Podrías modificar tu código un poquito a algo así. No es importante ni relevante pero queda más corto.

```js
const reducerPrueba5 = (state = null, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'AGREGAR_A_CARRITO':
   return action.vaciar ? state : action.carrito;
  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

Es difícil saber por qué te retorna `undefine`. Pero imagino que puede ser que en tu *action* no venga el atributo `carrito`. Viste si la acción te envía realmente este parámetro y de si lo hace cómo está llegando?.

Te recomiendo usar la librería *redux-logger*

https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger

Con esta librería, que es un middleware, podrás ver en la consola del navegador, todas tus acciones. También te muestra tu estado anterior y el posterior al cambio de estado. En las acciones podrás ver si estás enviando bien el parámetro que vas a usar.

Comment: Que tal Diego... Puedes Aclarar tu respuesta??  cual es el error del OP?? cual es tu solución y como has llegado a esa conclusión??  puedes darte una vuelta por [answer] para mas información.